# ExecuteScalar can only be called when the connection is open

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.forms

protected override async void OnAppearing()
{

```
        dbPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "OrderappDb.db");
        bool DbExists = File.Exists(dbPath);

        var connect = new SqliteConnection("Data Source=" + dbPath);
     

    private bool tableExists(SqliteConnection connection, string tableName)
    {
        dbPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "OrderappDb.db");
        var connect = new SqliteConnection("Data Source=" + dbPath);
        connection = connect;
        try
        {
            if (connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)

                connection.Open();
            using (cmd = new SqliteCommand(connection.ToString()))
            {
                //sqlite_master

                cmd.CommandText = $"Select Count(*) from sqlite_master where type='table' and name='{tableName}';";

                object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                //connection.Open();
                int resultCount = Convert.ToInt32(result);
                if (resultCount > 0)
                    return true;
                connection.Close();
                //  sqlite_master
            }
            return false;
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }



    }
```

I am Creating table in sqlite and aceesing that table.
Getting ,ExecuteScalar can only be called when the connection is open.Why I Am Getting above error dont understand. Please help  with my snippet.

Comment: Yes, check the [constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlite.sqlitecommand?view=msdata-sqlite-7.0.0#constructors), you should try `new SqliteCommand("SELECT * FROM ...", connection)`

Answer (score 0):

There is not an overload for `SqliteCommand` how you are using it. You'll want to use

```
Using SqliteCommand cmd = new SqliteCommand(yourSqlString, connection) {
    Integer val = cmd.executeScalar();
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlite.sqlitecommand?view=msdata-sqlite-7.0.0#constructors

Answer (score 0):

The `SqlCommand.ExecuteReader` Method Sends the `CommandText` to the Connection and builds a `SqlDataReader`. So it need `connection.Open();` method to open the connection and this is why the `ExecuteScalar` method can only be called when the connection open.